# How to consume the Open Weather App API in react

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openweathermap

I have been trying to fetch from the Open Weather API but an error message kept appearing on the console. It returned 'unauthorized' and 'message: keys does not exist' after persistent tries.

```
fetch("https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com/weather?callback=test&id=2172797&units=%22metric%22%20or%20%22imperial%22&mode=xml%2C%20html&q=London%2Cuk", {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com",
                "x-rapidapi-key": "15XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            }
```

Comment: You need to provide an API key as part of the URL. please see the docs https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys. if you simply want to use openweathermap API, see this https://openweathermap.org/appid

Comment: Also, this had nothing to do with react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using [rapidapi](https://rapidapi.com/) here, but if you simply want to fetch data from [openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/), you need to do the following:

- [Sign up](https://home.openweathermap.org/users/sign_up) to get unique API key (free plan exist)
- Provide the key as part of your URL, like:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY}`,
When `APIKEY` is your unique API key

Also make sure you do not use the API key from the demos provided by **open weather map**, as it will result with errors when used from domain other than `openweathermap`, And tha if you're using a free plan, you're limited to maxium of 60 request per minute.

Check out the docs about [how to get started with openweathermap](https://openweathermap.org/appid).

Comment: Exactly! I later did this and it worked. I made the mistake of not strictly following the openweathermap docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per the fetch function response, it looks like that the API key you are using is invalid or expired.
I'm able to replicate the issue in my setup.
I found one working API key on rapidapi site and after using the key the issue is resolved.

The working Key Api key is : 490f920aa3msh1db5e8f1c73a050p1cbd06jsn83595422113e

You can also use the above key as a quick workaround.